# PHP Functions to create form elements. Good Practice?

Tags: php, html

I'm not one for using plugins or anything, so I am trying to avoid things like Zend for now, but I wanted to see if it is good practice to create "Templates" with php functions?
I forget a lot of PHP right now and will get back into it once I get his answer, but I was thinking something like this:

PHP

```
function input($type, $label, $id, $class) {
    echo "<div>";
    echo "<input type=" .$type. " class=" .$class. " id=" .$id. />";
    echo "<label for=" .$id. ">".$label."</label>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <?PHP input("text", "Username", "username", "input"); ?>
</div>
```

Of course this code needs to be tweaked to my needs, but I am wondering if it would be considered good practice? or should I stray away from doing something like this?

Comment: it's only bad practice if you start working with someone who does it differently. "good practice" is like religion. some agree with it, some live and breathe it, some couldn't care less, some are deadset against it. e.g. right now I'd downvote you to -MAX_INT because you're using multiple echoes and string concatenation instead of a heredoc. others will crucify for not using a template engine, blah blah blah.

Comment: I don't see why there's anything wrong with creating your own frameworks that work for you. Other frameworks give you more time to work on your projects, but sometimes you need something that is fully customized to fit your needs.

Comment: Ha, Yes, I would downvote too if I were actually using that code.  I never use echo's for purposes other than echoing a simple string, I just needed to get my point accross.

Comment: Most frameworks already have these so why don't you write for your one ?

Comment: Very true Kacey.  I have been going back and forth with this and have restarted and recoded everything three times on this large project of mine every time I find something new to use...

Comment: @ayeshK, Another good point.  I am trying to get back into PHP again (I've been focusing a lot of time on front-end) and I appreciate your thoughts

Comment: For me, I'd go along with this code - it looks really useful. Like @MarcB said, it really is just about what you personally think is right and what works for you. Again, if you work in a professional environment, you'd need to work with co-workers to see what works best for all of you.

Comment: @mattios550 Awesome. thank you all.  I feel I've wasted all of your time (and server space!) and the answer should have been plain and simple.  So I apologize

Comment: You were right to come here - we're all looking for help and advice, and it is useful when people post code ideas like this ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see the comments and I hope you won't crucify me to say that most of people would agree on reusability: **return the value instead of echoing it**

```
function input($type, $label, $id, $class) {
  // create the div here ...
  return $divString;
}
```

and then work with the result as you wish...

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <?PHP echo input("text", "Username", "username", "input"); ?>
</div>
```

or use it another way like this

`$formElements = input("text", "Username", "username", "input") . input("password", "Password", "password", "input");`

Comment: Why is this necessary Jan? I have nothing against your method but I am just wondering if there is a real difference between `return` and `echo` in this context?

Comment: @Mattios550: Sometimes you may want to alter the result before echoing it. If you return the contents, you can use it as input for another function for higher abstraction layer. For example, you can create a class for creating forms using this function. Or you can build a string as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Yep, I see how that can help now. How would we call this function? Call me a n00b, but would it be like `input("text", "Username", "username", "input");`? Without the `echo` before it? +1'd.

Comment: @Mattios550: `$result = input(...)` - the `$result` can be echoed or further processed

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is good practice, but there are some improvements to be made. A better way to do it would be to use a class. This way, you can configure, clone, pass and extend inputs, and implement complex input types with very little effort.

Another way to do this would be to accept a key-value array containing each HTML attribute of the element, and outputting them in a given element type.

```
myElement = element(elementType, attributes); //Attributes: type=input, value=myvalue...
```

A second important improvement would be to correctly escape what goes inside each parameter to avoid XSS injection.

All of this is usually covered by most frameworks, and can easily be copied without including the entire framework in your project.

Answer (score 1):

It's something we call a "Helper". So yes, it's absolutely a good practice. But all PHP framework implement that. You can try CakePHP !